# Build CI/CD Pipeline with Github Actions, Helm and Argo CD

Tags: continuous-integration, kubernetes-helm, github-actions, continuous-deployment, argocd

I have a Git Repo where my Application Code and Helm Manifests are located. On commit to the Directory where my Application Code is located i trigger a docker build and push the new Image to my private Repository.

Argo on the other Hand is watching the Helm Manifests for a change, and deploying to my Kubernetes Cluster, however only, if I change the tag of the image in the Helm value File.

Any Idea how i can avoid this manual step to have a fully automated Pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

write a script which will clone the helm repo and change the image tag using `yq`.

Like below

```
git clone giturl
yq w -i chart_name/values.yaml image.tag $image_tag.
git config user.email "test@test.com"
git config user.name "test"
git add .
git commit -m "changed"
git push
```

Now take the image tag as variable $image_tag and run the above script after pushing docker image.
Please check [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) here.
And ofcourse, runing this script will be depended on how you are creating docker images.If you use docker autobuild then consider post_build hook.If its in github actions then add another stage.

Comment: Thanks, managed to fully automate my pipeline. I used the following yq command
`yq -i eval '.image.tag = "test-value"' metrics-collector-helm/values.yaml`